# Align list item in responsive view

Tags: css, html

In my html i have a list with with a class tick.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li class="tick">Active directory management</li>
</ul>
li.tick:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: #1ABC9B;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbtth71o/)

But it have responsive issue when resizing it.
[image]

How to align 'management' exactly below the 'Active'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li.tick {
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

li.tick:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: #1ABC9B;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

li.tick:before {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 20px;
    content: "\2713";
    color: #1ABC9B;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li class="tick">Active directory management</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
<style>
        ul {
            display: flex;
        }
        .tick-before::after {
            content: "\2713";
            color: #1ABC9B;
            padding-right: 8px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
       <div class="tick-before"></div>
        <li class="tick">Active directory management</li>

    </ul>
</body>
```